# php preg_match multiple urls

Tags: php

I know next to nothing about php so this will make someone laugh probably.

I have this bit of code in index.php which checks a host header and redirects if a match is found.

```
if (!preg_match("/site1.net.nz/",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://www.siteblah.net.nz/temp_internet_block.cfm');
}
```

However, I need to make it check on potentially multiple sites. as follows.

```
if (!preg_match("/site1.net.nz/"|"/site2.net.nz",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://www.siteblah.net.nz/temp_internet_block.cfm');
}
```

This might actually be the correct syntax for all I know:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// [12] to match 1 or 2
// also need to escape . for match real . otherwise . will match any char
if (!preg_match("/site[12]\.net\.nz/",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://www.siteblah.net.nz/temp_internet_block.cfm');
}
```

Or

```
if (!preg_match("/site1\.net\.nz|site2\.net\.nz/",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://www.siteblah.net.nz/temp_internet_block.cfm');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it might not always be similar urls. Ideally, maybe I need an array where I can just add another url as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match("/(site1\.net\.nz|site2\.net\.nz|some\.other\.domain)/",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://www.siteblah.net.nz/temp_internet_block.cfm');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$hosts="/(site1\.com)|(site2\.com)/";
if (!preg_match($hosts,$host)) {
  // do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/(site1\.net\.nz|site2\.net\.nz)/",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://www.siteblah.net.nz/temp_internet_block.cfm');
}
```

This would be correct RegEx syntax.

Let's say you have an array of urls.

```
$array = Array('site1.net.nz', 'site2.net.nz');

foreach($array as &$url) {
   // we need to escape the url properly for the regular expression
   // eg. 'site1.net.nz' -> 'site1\.net\.nz'
   $url = preg_quote($url);
}

if (!preg_match("/(" . implode("|",  $array) . ")/",$host)) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/');
}
```